# How do I change the ios simulator in Flutter?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, simulator

I changed the simulator in Xcode but when I opened it on Android Studio, it always opens the same one
How do I change the simulator for Flutter?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

On Mac when you open Simulator go to

**File -> Open Simulator -> iOS...**